# jQuery on() selector assistance required

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have some issues with understanding jQuery on.

If i have a UL which has some dynamic Li elements created via jquery, which will set the first li to have the class selected - e.g.

```
<li class='selected'>text</li>
```

EDIT UDPATE:

Ok..so what i have is a set of dynamically generated LI from a REST call which is dynamically generated from a text box.  What i need to happen is to essentially  after i type in (keyup) i will get some results displayed (similar to autocomplete).  What i then need to do is from within the context of the search box detect the up and down arrows and move the ".selected" class up and down the tree.  The code below works for static lists, just not dynamically created ones.

some example code:

```
$('.txtSearchBox')
.unbind('keypress keyup')
.bind('keypress keyup', function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length < 3 && e.keyCode != 13) {
        $('.searchWrapper').hide();
    } else {
        $('.searchWrapper').show();
        SearchAutoComplete.init($('.searchWrapper'));
        SearchAutoComplete.load();
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $(".searchWrapper li").removeClass("selected");
        if (selected.prev().length == 0) {
            selected.parent().children().last().addClass("selected");
        } else {
            selected.prev().addClass("selected");
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $(".searchWrapper li").removeClass("selected");
        if (selected.next().length == 0) {
            selected.parent().children().first().addClass("selected");
        } else {
            selected.next().addClass("selected");
        }
    }
});

$(".searchWrapper li").live('mouseover', function (e) {
    $(".searchWrapper li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

As you can see this code detects the up and down arrow keys.  The problem is for dynamic elements this does nothing.  Im just confused as the on event should be on the li not the a?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Two people have showed you how to use `on()`. Apply the knowledge to your key pressing events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".searchWrapper ul").on('mouseover',"li", function () {
    $(".searchWrapper li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

From the JQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) when you provide a selector to the `on()` function ("li") the event handler is delegated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uV9mN/)

With an [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) you can iterate through your elements and manipulate them as you wish.

```
$('ul.alist li').on('click', function(){

jQuery.each($('ul.alist li'), function() {
  $(this).removeClass('selected');

});
});
```

With the above code all I am doing is iterating through the li tags and removing the 'selected' class.